# NGINX 404 - reverser proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

The following is my file(default.conf) for nginx reverse proxy under /conf.d

```
server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;

            # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
            server_name localhost;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://www.paypal.com;
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rule
            }

            location /abc/{
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_pass http://www.google.com;
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rule
            }

            location /xyz/{
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_pass http://www.youtube.com;
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rule
            }
```

When I hit my ip directly I am redirected to paypal but when I hit my **ip/abc** or **/ip/xyz** , I am getting 404

Comment: What else did you expect? And why?

Comment: I was expecting to be redirected to google.com when I hit myip/abc

Comment: Why? Google responded 404, you get it.

Comment: No Sir, this is the first time I am working with nginx. I will be thankful to you if you could explain me the reason and the things which I am doing wrong

Comment: I don't know I am correct or not but google responded with 404 because google does not understand my URI eg : www.google.com/abc.

Thanks for the hint sir.